# JQuery Mobile swiperight is not opening panel

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, swipe

I think the question title is self explanatory, I've just set a script to handle a right swipe on my page, it should open my left panel, but I don't really know why is not working ..

The head script:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="JQuery/JQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="JQuery/JQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="JQuery/JQueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" />

<script>
    $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#homepage", function() {
        $( document ).on( "swiperight", "#homepage", function( e ) {
            if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
                if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
                    $( "#mypanel" ).panel( "open" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The page:

```
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="homepage" data-url="homepage">    

        <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-display="push">
            <!-- panel content goes here -->
        </div><!-- /panel -->

        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#mypanel" data-icon="grid">Menu</a>
            <h1>Projecto Colibri</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <p>Page content goes here.</p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
            <nav data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="shop">Artigos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="user">Clientes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="gear">Fornecedores</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div><!-- /footer -->

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where are you putting the script? Just created a fiddle with your code and it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/48GU3/

Comment: @ezanker , in my head section, and it seems to be working again, but now it's swaping the entire page to my index instead of swiping the panel ... ps: I've updated the post with the head section